# Accepting Payments To Bitcoins

Tags: payment, ripple-gateways

I am setting up an online shop to sell digital goods. I would ideally like to accept only Bitcoin payments, however most users do not use Bitcoins or can't work it out. Therefore, I have to accept credit cards, Paypal, etc. to actually make a profit. My question: is there a service that provides all of these payment gateways but can then combine each service to a Bitcoin wallet?

For example, customer A pays by Paypal, customer B with Skrill. Both payments go into a single account where I can then withdraw the money to a Bitcoin wallet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any service that handles all of these. You can use [Coinbase](https://coinbase.com/merchants) to accept bitcoin.  If your Paypal account deposits the fiat to a U.S. bank account, you can also use Coinbase to manually "buy" Bitcoin into the same Coinbase account.

If you knew the value of your USD account, you could automate the buying of bitcoin via [Coinbase API](https://coinbase.com/docs/api/overview).  Manually doing the conversion every week, month, etc would not be a bad idea though because you could wait until the Bitcoin price is low, or just keep a part of the funds in fiat for your business expenses.

If you are outside the U.S., probably better to look into Bitpay.

Answer (score 0):

Check our API

https://bitaps.com/api/

No registration or API keys required.
No country limits

In case you need support contact support@bitaps.com